# Get ID of clicked element which opened context menu using jQuery contextMenu Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, contextmenu

I use the [jQuery contextMenu](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/index.html) from Rodney Rehm in an SVG graphic. It works fine for basic usage.

But I need to get the ID (or any other property) of the SVG-Element which triggered the context menu to use it in the context menu's item list to get dynamic item names.

I work with the [Simple Context Menu](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html) demo and now want to replace these static menu items with dynamic ones depending on the ID of the SVG element which was clicked on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This may help you: http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/dynamic-create.html
Here's some sample code:

```
$(function(){
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: 'my-selector-here', 
        build: function($trigger, e) {
            // this callback is executed every time the menu is to be shown
            // its results are destroyed every time the menu is hidden
            // e is the original contextmenu event, containing e.pageX and e.pageY (amongst other data)
            // $trigger is the element that was rightclicked on - get its id here
            var id = $trigger.getTheIDSomehow()
            // build the menu items
            if (id == 1) {
              menuItems = {...}
            else if (id == 2)
              menuItems = {...}
            return {
                callback: function(key, options) {
                    // this is called when one of the contextmenu options is clicked
                },
                items: menuItems
            };
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I knew that demo. My problem is just to get the ID. So, how can I get the ID of the triggering element? (So, I search the right function for your "getTheIDSomehow".

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I knew that demo, but didn't see the solution. I got it finally.

Answer (score 13):

when I use the static menus, I get the id like this:

```
...
callback: function (key, options) {
    id = options.$trigger.attr("id");
    ...
},
...
```

Maybe $trigger.attr("id") could work for you.

Answer (score 10):

You Just have to check the on which Element the right click is done as::

```
$.contextMenu({
            selector: 'tr',
            callback: function (key, options) {
                var m = "clicked: " + key;
                if (key == "Clone") 
               {
                    Your_Function($(this).attr('id'));
               }

            },
            items: {
                "Clone": { name: "Clone" },
                }
            });
```